# Why is script not being executed?

Tags: bash, apache-pig, alias

Using OSX, I downloaded pig-0.11.1 as is and created an alias in my bashrc. I have the following alias:

> alias pigalias='/dev/pig-0.11.1/bin/pig -D
>   udf.import.list=org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro -D
>   pig.additional.jars=/dev/avro-1.7.4.jar;/dev/avro-mapred-1.7.4.jar;/dev/json_simple-1.1.jar;/Users/devpig-0.11.1/contrib/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar'

The issue is when I run something like:

```
piglias myscript.pig
```

The grunt shell pops up, but does not appear to actually execute my script.

Note: I am also getting `/dev/avro-mapred-1.7.4.jar: Permission Denied`. The file is set to have a chmod of 644 (read for everyone).

Update: After adding double quotes around the parameter, I am getting a:

```
/dev/avro-1.7.4.jar;/dev/avro-mapred-1.7.4.jar;/dev/json_simple-1.1.jar;/Users/devpig-0.11.1/contrib/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar' does not exist.
```

Those files clearly exist. Each of them.

Comment: Semicolon is a command separator, you need to put the parameters to `-D` in quotes to prevent this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need quotes around the `-D` parameters that contain semicolons, otherwise it will terminate the command.

```
alias pigalias='/dev/pig-0.11.1/bin/pig -D udf.import.list=org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro -D "pig.additional.jars=/dev/avro-1.7.4.jar;/dev/avro-mapred-1.7.4.jar;/dev/json_simple-1.1.jar;/Users/devpig-0.11.1/contrib/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar"'
```

You're getting the `Permission denied` error because you're trying to execute `/dev/avro-mapred-1.7.4.jar` as a program, since it's after the semicolon, and it doesn't have execute permission.

Comment: Getting an ERROR101 file '/dev/avro-1.7.4.jar;/dev/avro-mapred-1.7.4.jar;/dev/json_simple-1.1.jar;/Users/devpig-0.11.1/contrib/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar' does not exist.

Comment: That sounds to me like you're not supposed to separate the files with semicolon. Maybe it uses colon? I don't know anything about pig.